# How to logout from facebook or destroy an active session using php?

Tags: facebook, session, logout

I have an application which asks for a registration through facebook but before a user can proceed to the registration, the system should first determine if there is an **active session**. If a user is logged in to **facebook**, it should then automatically logout for a fresh start.

But here is where I'm stuck. The SDKs only let the user log out from facebook if he is connected to your app. It uses the app's access token. But what if he is still not registered to your app? Their log out means to log out from your app, and not really from facebook.

**My requirement :**

**1.** How can i log out from facebook.

**2.** How can i clear the browser cookies?

**Not on a specific app but the whole facebook session.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [from comments] But to use the getLogoutUrl() function, the user has to be connected to your app. What I need is to logout from the whole facebook and not just from the app

If the user is connected to your app, then the URL provided by the `getLogoutUrl` method does that – log the user out of your app (web-app) *and* out of facebook.com.

If the user is *not* connected to your app however, you don’t have an active user access token – and then logging out of Facebook is not possible. The obvious reason being that if it was, every website that I visit could log me out of Facebook in a “drive-by” manner – without me actively wanting that, so people would get annoyed quite quickly.

> If a user is logged in to facebook, it should then automatically logout for a fresh start.

If this is a security consideration, then you are in fact looking for [re-authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-re-auth/), which can be done using the `auth_type` parameter, quote from docs:

> *In apps where security is very important, you may want to double-check someone's identity - perhaps before they make a purchase within the app, or use it to access some sensitive personal data.*
>
> *To prevent situations where a user could leave a device logged in or man-in-the-middle hijacking of the user session, re-authentication forces a person to re-enter their Facebook password before they can continue to use your app.*

Be aware to use the *server-side* Auth flow though – because in the client-side flow, using the JS SDK, there is a bug that allows the user to bypass re-entering his password by simply closing the popup, which is still open: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/248632218597467 (Has been assigned *Priority: High*, but received still nothing more than a *“we will follow up”* response yet.)

Comment: hi thank you very much for answering and giving me idea about re-authentication. That's also what I thought of but I was just kinda hoping that my issue will be solved. At least I'm pretty convinced that it wouldn't be possible because just as you said, it would ask for an access token and that I can't fully control the logging out of user from fb.

Answer (score 0):

Use the logout.php url.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLogoutUrl/

Basically,

```
 http://facebook.com/logout.php?next=YOUR_NEXT_URL_FOR_LOGOUT&access_token=USER_TOKEN
```

Comment: hi there, thanks! But to use the getLogoutUrl() function, the user has to be connected to your app. What I need is to logout from the whole facebook and not just from the app. :(

Comment: @sarenagay then I'm not really sure, ` the system should first determine if there is an active session. If a user is logged in to facebook, it should then automatically logout for a fresh start.` this doesn't make sense either, if the session is active why would you want to logout? Unless multiple users are interacting from the same point...

Comment: it's for security purposes. i think i would just opt for the re-authentication instead of logging out. thanks a lot btw :)

Answer (score 0):

1) logging out from facebook by using

```
facebook=>getLogoutUrl();
```

2) clearing the session by using :

```
$facebook->destroySession();
```

example:

```
<a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
```

logout.php page codes as follow:

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';
$facebook->destroySession();
header( "location:index.php" );
?>
```